# function within ng-if block not working

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Hi I tried to use angular and localstorage for authentication. and i meet this problem.

below is part of code in my app.js

```
app.run(function($window,$rootScope){

    $rootScope.isAuthed=function(){
        console.log("starting isAuthed...."+$window.localStorage.getItem("isAuthenticated"))
        return $window.localStorage.getItem("isAuthenticated")
    }
    $rootScope.whoIsCurrenUser=function(){
        return $window.localStorage.getItem("currentUser")
    }

    $rootScope.logout=function(){
        if(confirm("Are you sure to log out ?")){
            $window.localStorage.setItem("isAuthenticated", false);
            $window.localStorage.setItem("currentUser", "");
        }
    }
})
```

And in my html, i tried to apply the isAuthed function within ng-if but it doesn't work

```
 <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
                    <li ng-if="!isAuthed()"><a ng-click="loginDialog()">Log In</a></li>
                    <li ng-if="isAuthed()"><a ng-click="logout()">Log Out</a></li>
  </ul>
```

And i can see on console the isAuthenticated set to true
[image]

but there's no either login or logout showing on my page..

[image]

My Question as in the title of this post:  why function within ng-if block not working ?

Comment: looks more like layout or css problem since neither element appears in your image. Also note that localStorage only stores strings, not booleans

Comment: What happens if you remove the ng-if directive? Are the links shown? A Fiddle would be handy

Comment: thanks for reminding me that localstorage only stores string.. And if remove ng-if , links will shown up

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An easy solution is to compare the result of isAuthed function with a string as "true". The code could be:

```
$rootScope.isAuthed=function(){
    console.log("starting isAuthed...."+$window.localStorage.getItem("isAuthenticated"))
    return $window.localStorage.getItem("isAuthenticated") === "true";
}
```

Comment: Hi, you're welcome. If you used this solution, it would be great if you mark it as the right answer.

Answer (score 1):

LocalStorage saves [strings](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Storage/getItem).

> **Returns** A DOMString containing the value of the key. If the key does not exist, null is returned.

Both `"true"` and `"false"` are truthy. You need to parse data before returning. Or use empty string to represent `false` value. [Demo](http://plnkr.co/edit/IyzgTuHK7uAmbLR44h5D?p=preview).

```
app.run(function($window,$rootScope){

    $rootScope.isAuthed=function(){
        console.log("starting isAuthed...."
                + (typeof $window.localStorage.getItem("isAuthenticated"))
                + $window.localStorage.getItem("isAuthenticated"))
        return JSON.parse($window.localStorage.getItem("isAuthenticated"))
    }
```

Comment: Yep you're right both "true" and "false" are truthy.